# Let's view flags by type and how they were handled

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-history

On my flagging history page, I'm told that I have *X* moderator attention flags, of which *Y* were marked helpful, *Z* were disputed, and *W* were declined, and the same for spam, offensive, and comment flags.

My [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is to allow viewing of flags by type and how they were handled, similar to how the activity or votes tab of the user profile page can be broken down into sections.

I think this is a good idea, because if people can review their flags easily, users whose flags are declined often will find it easier to figure out *why* they were declined, so that they can learn from the experience.